# How to efficiently flatten pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have below dataframe

```
df.show()


 +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|           PKG_NBR|       PKG_VINS        |     PKG_DIAGNOSYS  |    PKG_TYPES       |        PKG_PAYERS  |
+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|qw3dcc0-5da3-447... |[{Billing, 2, 184... |[{Admitting, 0, 3...|[{1, 2014-09-23, ...|[{1, MA, MEA}, {2...|
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- PKG_NBR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PKG_VINS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- VIN_ROLE_NM: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- VIN_ENTITY_TYPE_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- VIN_NPI_NBR: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- VIN_OMNY_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PKG_DIAGNOSYS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- sensor_TYPE_NM: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sensor_SEQUENCE_VAL: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sensor_UAT_ID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sensor_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PKG_TYPES: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- TYPE_SEQUENCE_VAL: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- SERVICE_DD: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- TYPE_UAT_ID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- TYPE_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PKG_PAYERS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- PAYER_SEQUENCE_ID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PKG_FILING_INDICATOR_CD: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PAYER_PLAN_SUBCHANNEL_CD: string (nullable = true)
```

I am flattening the dataframe to get the individual column name using this:

```
cols_to_explode=['PKG_VINS','PKG_DIAGNOSYS', 'PKG_TYPES', 'PKG_PAYERS']
other_cols = [F.col(c) for c in df.schema.names if c not in cols_to_explode]
struct_cols = list(chain(*[[F.col(col + "." + c).alias(col + "." + c) for c in df.withColumn(col, F.explode(col)).selectExpr( col + ".*").columns] for col in df.schema.names if col in cols_to_explode]))
df = df.withColumn("asZipped", F.arrays_zip(*cols_to_explode)).withColumn("asZipped", F.explode("asZipped")).select(other_cols + [F.col("asZipped." + col).alias(col) for col in df.schema.names if col in cols_to_explode]).select(other_cols + struct_cols)
```

For the above example for `PKG_DIAGNOSYS, PKG_TYPES and PKG_PAYERS` has more than 3 different values in the list but for PKG_VINS there is only one item in list.

Using the above code when I am doing df.show(), IT'S giving me all column but values for

```
PKG_VINS.VIN_ROLE_NM, PKG_VINS.VIN_ENTITY_TYPE_CD, PKG_VINS.VIN_NPI_NBR,
PKG_VINS.VIN_OMNY_CD
```

all coming null values except for the first row.

|

```
PKG_NBR                                |PKG_VINS.PROVIDER_ROLE_NM       |PKG_VINS.VIN_ENTITY_TYPE_CD            |PKG_VINS.VIN_NPI_NBR            |PKG_VINS.VIN_OMNY_CD            |PKG_DIAGNOSYS.sensor_TYPE_NM     
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------------------- ..... other flattened columns
|qw3dcc0-5da3-447-5da3-4472-8444-a3697f |Billing                         |2                                      |1811163494                      |282N00000X                          |Admitting                        
|qw3dcc0-5da3-447-5da3-4472-8444-a3697f |null                            |null                                   |null                            |null                                |Principal     
|qw3dcc0-5da3-447-5da3-4472-8444-a3697f |null                            |null                                   |null                            |null                                |Principal1
```

How can I fix this?

Is there any better way to do flatten the data with out using hardcoded column names to flatten. Basically I want to flatten the data whenever any struct column encounters like this and the column name should `'.'` separated